# SAML error in log

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I tried enable saml in my test server, according to the below link http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndsebetaforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=C6F8337CA6DCC1FB85257AD300574EF3

after all the set up i'm not redirecting to IDP as instructed.

my log says

"01/30/2013 10:21:24 AM  HTTP Server: Error reading IdP configuration for for server  :Invalid arguments
01/30/2013 10:21:24 AM  HTTP Server: SAML configuration error.  SAML is enabled for server [], but no active IdP configuration could be loaded."

so i tried recreating IDP configuration  error remains same , help me what could be the reson , are what should i do to recreate the IDP

Thanks

Comment: Now Its resolved , have created fresh configuration.

Comment: Maybe you want to create an answer where you describe in more detail what you did. I'd be interested to know since I will have to configure SAML at some point too.

Comment: I don't know how to configure ACL for domino application as it needs to compatible with IDP active directory. 

After SAML setup I'm redirecting to IDP, after give valid user name and password i'm getting the below error.Can anyone help me on this?


Error->
MS.saml.local
There was a problem accessing the site. Try to browse to the site again.
If the problem persists, contact the administrator of this site and provide the reference number to identify the problem.
Reference number: 0446e7ed-da3e-115-9d07-6c3852fe4b68

Comment: It's probably a good idea to create a new question about this.

Comment: Let me do that too Thank you

Comment: I was able to get the production meta data to works but when I import QA meta data XML I get the same errors as you, even if I remove the empty lines from certificates. I have no IPs in IdP configuration document.

Answer (score 1):

The message was caused by newline characters in 509 cert strings. I had to remove all of them, in the beginning, in the middle and at the end of the cert strings.

Comment: This message contributes nothing new

Comment: I got this "Error reading IdP configuration for server <xxx host.domain>:Invalid arguments" and that was also fixed by removing all new lines from both certificates.

Answer (score 0):

@Panu Previously i used IP address in few Fields (of IDP configuration) instead of using full name of domino server now i have changed that, after confirming both domino and windows servers are able contact using that full name .

Now my domino login is redirecting me to IDP , but have not completed yet.

Below PDF has complete details on SAML

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndsebetaforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=2121CA50A3EDE66485257AD30049EAE1

Comment: I'm finally configuring SAML. Was getting exactly the same errors. I had imported metadata xml which works with Shibboleth. These errors finally disappeared when I removed the empty line from the beginning and end of certificate! These lines were generated by the import. Now I'm getting "Error processing authentication configuration for MyCompany: Active IdP catalog entry found.  Overriding configuration and enabling SAML authentication at ip.ip.ip.ip.". Looks like I need to dedicate an IP for SAML login.

Comment: OK I got rid of the IP note by removing the server IP from IdP Configuration. Now only server dns name there.

Comment: Now also the QA metadata is working. The last line of encryption certificate was 4 chars. I moved the last line to the end of the second last line and it started to work!